# How to give option to print a bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

My question is simple and limited , I want to print a bootstrap table having an Id ("myTbl") so how can I make it possible with javascript / jquery ?(I dont want to use plugins)

---

I am newbie in using jquery and bootstrap please help

Comment: do you have a solution? if yes, please post it

Answer (score 2):

```
   <script>
   $(function () {
        $('button[type="submit"]').click(function () {
            var pageTitle = 'Page Title',
                stylesheet = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                win = window.open('', 'Print', 'width=500,height=300');
            win.document.write('<html><head><title>' + pageTitle + '</title>' +
                '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + stylesheet + '">' +
                '</head><body>' + $('#myTbl')[0].outerHTML + '</body></html>');
            win.document.close();
            win.print();
            win.close();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>


     <button class="btn  btn-default" type="submit">Print Item</button>
```

Comment: you know ? you saved my day . Thanks